# ClassNotFoundException: io.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpRequest cannot be found

Tags: http, httprequest, netty, handler

I have following dependencies in my pom.xml

```
 <dependency>
            <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
            <artifactId>netty-buffer</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
            <artifactId>netty-transport</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
            <artifactId>netty-handler</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
            <artifactId>netty-codec</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
            <artifactId>netty-codec-http</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

Still when the bundle is executed it gives above CNF exception. I even tried adding below dependency. Still not working. Any idea on how to solve?

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
    <artifactId>netty-all</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.30.Final</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: How are you executing your final product?

Comment: If it's OSGI then you either has bad scope in POM (should be provided, not compile) or you should have problems with imports during bundle start.Examine bundle's MANIFEST

Comment: If you working with netbeans, have you already tried to restart that piece of chunk? ;) Netbeans sometime just don't want to find the dependencies.